# How can I run composer update without any resulting HTTP calls?

Tags: php, composer-php

I was wondering if there is a way to use `composer update` without querying packagist.org for all the packages.

My problem is that as I update local `composer.json` I have to run `composer update` since I get messages like this when simply running `composer install`:

> Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.

So what I want is to only update the dependencies and then grab any of the required ones from cache.  I believe http calls to check for newer version is causing a huge slowdown.

Comment: There’s no good reason to *edit* `composer.json` in order to add, remove, or update packages. All of this can be achieved by running `composer require` or `composer remove`, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require and https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#remove.

Comment: @localheinz there are other settings in composer.json, such as local repositories and autoload settings.

Comment: Sure, but if you read my comment above I’m talking about cases of updating, adding, and removing packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of running

```
$ composer update
```

is to *update* all of the dependencies required via `composer.json`. In order to find out whether any of the dependencies need updating, `composer` connects to https://packagist.org, the central package meta data repository, to inquire whether any of the packages currently required are available in newer versions that match the respective version constraints.

You can disable using Packagist via configuration:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "packagist.org": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Alternatively, you can use private Packagist or Satis to speed up the process.

Generally, I would encourage to use

```
$ composer install
```

to install dependencies as locked in `composer.lock`, or run

```
$ composer require foo/bar:^x.y.z —update-with-dependencies
```

or run

```
$ composer remove foo/bar
```

to add, update and remove packages, instead of editing `composer.json` and then running

```
$ composer update
```

Updating all packages at once has the following disadvantages

- it doesn’t explicitly document what the actual minimum version of a required package should be
- it could potentially pull in breaking changes, and depending on whether you have sufficient test coverage, you might have a hard time finding out what caused problems here

Limiting the updates to one at a time makes it easier to find issues. Also, there’s no good reason to just update every dependency at once (unless you want to find out whether an application or library works with the latest dependencies in a Continuous Integration environment). Normally, you want to update a single dependency (or a small set of dependencies) in order to

- pull in updates that fix bugs
- pull in updates that provide specific features you intend to use

For reference, see

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#disabling-packagist-org
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#private-packagist
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#satis
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#remove